# Is it possible to replace the first line of a code if it is not a particular string?

Tags: replace, lua, line

I am trying to ensure a post processor for g-code always writes the first line of a file correctly. When the post errors out, the first line of code written contains whatever was last in the buffer. Such as G01X3.45Y5.63% when the first line is supposed to only be %.

I am looking for a way to open the specified file, check to see if the first line is only "%" and if not replace it with "%".

I am very new to lua. I have found methods to replace the first line of code and methods to replace a specific string, but no way to check to see if the string needs to be replaced. Just tring to make the code as efficient as possible.

I found this in another forum and was hoping for a way to adapt it to check if the first line needs to be replaced.

```lua
--First lets read the file and put the contents in a table name tContents
local file = io.open("example.txt", "r")
sContents = file:read() -- capture file in a string
file:close()
tContents = textutils.unserialize(sContents) -- convert string to table

--Print a specific line
print (tContents[3])

--Modify a specific line
table.remove(tContents, 3) -- will remove line 3 so we can insert the new line 3
table.inserct(tContents, 3, "New Information") -- inserts the string "New Infomation" on line 3 in the table.

--Convert table to string and save the file
sContents = textutils.serialize(tContents)
local file = io.open("example.txt", "w")
file:write(sContents)
file:close()
```

I am sure i can modify this to do as i need, i just do not know how to do the necessary if statement.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4  it's all in the manual. Come on!

Comment: @Piglet Honestly i have tried but i cannot make sense of that and get what i need. Also it appears the textutils command in the code above wont work for me.